# how to communicate between kubernetes operators

Tags: kubernetes, operators, communication, kubernetes-operator

I have a kubernetes operator that I want to deploy in a multi-cluster environment.For example, imagine that we have two clusters, and the operator will exist in both. I want it to be possible for them to communicate with each other to, for example, move workloads in order to optimize costs. For example, the cost in cluster 1 has reached the limit. It is necessary for the operator of this cluster to communicate with the operator of the other cluster to launch instances of the application, for example. Having said that, what would be the best way to communicate between operators who are equal.Im using operator framework and Go to develop my operator.

I expected to me able to send messages between the various instances of the operator.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.